# PHP wrong date and time

Tags: php, apache, date, centos, timezone

In my Centos 8 the Systems date is correct:

```
[server@user ~]$ date
gio 28 nov 2019, 16.07.05, CET
```

But in my PHP 7.3 by Remi instance with correct timezone, the date and time are wrong.
[image]

[image]

I already set correctly date.timezone in php.in (and already restart apache).

I don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: The PHP date, is the data the code of PHP was build. It is not the current date.

Comment: Try to restart "php-fpm".

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Rome");
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
?>
```